# RSpec: How to test existence of keys in an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, hash, rspec

I have a class:

```
class ApiParser
  def initialize
    ..
  end

  def api_data
    # returns an array of hashes like so:
    # [{ answer: "yes", name: "steve b" age: 22, hometown: "chicago", ... },
    # { answer:"unsure", name: "tom z", age: 44, hometown: "baltimore" , ... },
    # { answer: "no", name: "the brah", age: nil, hometown: "SF", ... }, 
    # { ... }, { ... }, ... ]
  end
end
```

The method returns an array of hashes.  The length of the array is 50 elements.

Each hash has the exact same keys.  There are around 20 keys.

I am not sure what would be the best way to unit test this method. How can I check that the method is indeed returning an array with each hash having these keys?  Some of the hash values may be nil, so I do not think I will test the values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will help:

```
describe "your test description" do
  let(:hash_keys) { [:one, :two].sort } # and so on

  subject(:array) { some_method_to_fetch_your_array }

  specify do
    expect(array.count).to eq 50

    array.each do |hash|
      # if you want to ensure only required keys exist
      expect(hash.keys).to contain_exactly(*hash_keys)
      # OR if keys are sortable
      # expect(hash.keys.sort).to eq(hash_keys)

      # if you want to ensure that at least the required keys exist
      expect(hash).to include(*hash_keys)
    end
  end
end
```

One problem with that approach: if the test fails, you'll have trouble finding out exactly which array index caused the failure. Adding a custom error message will help. **Something** like the following:

```
array.each_with_index do |hash, i|
  expect(hash.keys).to contain_exactly(*hash_keys), "Failed at index #{i}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help with only one line

```rb
describe '#api_data' do
  subject { ApiParser.new.api_data }
  let(:expected_keys) { [:key1, :key2, :key3] }

  it { is_expected.to all(contain_exactly(expected_keys)) }
end
```

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `arr` is the array of hashes. Let:

```
a = arr.map { |h| h.keys.sort }.uniq
```

then all the hashes have the same `n` keys if and only if:

```
a.size == 1 && a.first.size == n
```

That's easy to test.

If you were given the required keys in an array `keys`, then the test is:

```
a.size == 1 && a.first == keys.sort
```

Comment: Hey Cary. This testing code isn't very descriptive, which goes against what RSpec tries to accomplish. And this won't indicate which hash/ array-index failed. And it will outright fail for un-sortable keys e.g. `arr = [{1 => 'val1', '2' => 'val2'}]`.

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different tact at it. The error reports don't tell you much, but they let you know to look:

```
describe 'User Management: `/api/users`', type: :request do
  let(:required_keys) { %i(id email created_at updated_at) }
  let(:optional_keys) {
    %i(first_name last_name gender birthday bio phone role                                                                                     
       profile_image_url notification_preferences custom_group_order                                                                            
       archived timezone)
  }
  let(:keys) { required_keys + optional_keys }

  shared_examples 'a user object' do
    it 'has values for required keys' do
      subject.slice(*required_keys).values.should all be
    end

    its(:keys) { should include(*keys) }
  end

  shared_examples 'a users collection' do
    it { should be_an(Array) }

    it 'has all defined keys' do
      subject.map(&:keys).should all include(*keys)
    end

    it 'has values for required keys' do
      subject.map_send(:slice, *required_keys).map(&:values).flatten.should all be
    end
  end
end
```

The danger with these is they don't require a user collection to be non-empty. If an empty array is returned, these pass.

I include these test in one that makes an appropriate check for size:

```
describe 'GET to /api/users/visible' do
  let(:user) { Fabricate(:user) }

  subject { json[:users] }

  shared_examples 'a correct response' do
    it_should_behave_like 'a users collection'

    specify { controller.should respond_with :success }

    it { should have(members.size).items }

    it 'returns matching user ids' do
      ids(subject).should =~ ids(members)
    end
  end

  context 'with no groups' do
    let(:members) { [] }

    before { get '/api/users/visible', nil, auth_headers(user) }

    it_should_behave_like 'a correct response'
  end
end
```

The `json` and `ids` methods are just:

```
def json
  JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true) if response.try(:body).try(:present?)
end

def ids(*from)
  Array.wrap(*from).map do |item|
    if item.respond_to?(:id)
      item.send(:id)
    elsif item.is_a?(Hash)
      item[:id] || item['id']
    end
  end
end
```